# ToC for svmult with \include

Tags: table-of-contents, include, sv-classes

I am editing a book with multiple contributions using Springer's svmult document class. To include the single contributions into one document I am making plain use of \include{}. All goes fine up to here. However, when I am trying to create a \tableofcontents not only does it not create a table of contents, it doesn't even compile a pdf.

I am a bit hesitant to list all the packages used because there are a lot which, however, seem to interact well with one another. So I am hoping that there is an easy explanation that doesn't blame any of the packages loaded.

```
\documentclass{svmult} \begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\frontmatter

\include{X}

\mainmatter

\part{ONE}

\include{Y}

\part{TWO}

\include{Z} \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question is clear, but it may be improved a bit. Specifically, the goal of the code example should be that it allows to reproduce the issue. So it this case you should try to write some minimal X, Y and Z files that cause the current code sample to produce errors and/or no table of contents, and edit those files into your question using the `edit` button below the post.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I added `\usepackage{blindtext}` and created `X.tex`, `Y.tex`, `Z.tex` all containing `\blinddocument`. The table of contents is produced with no problem.